# SQL query relational issue

Tags: sql

I have a donor table and certificate table. 
The donor table has the attributes

```
(one)
Donor No*
Donor Name
Donor Address
Donor Phone
Donor E-mail
```

And is a one to many relationship in the Certificate table with attributes

```
(many)
Certificate No*
Certificate Type
Certificate Issue Date
```

What SQL statement can be used to find the amount of donors that recieved a specific type of certificate i.e gold, silver bronze

I've tried

```
select count (*) from Donor.Certificate where Certificate = gold ect...
```

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: And how is the certificate table related to the donor table ? There should be a DonorNo attribute in the Certificate table.  Is there?  Or are the asterisks supposed to mean that the `CertificateNo` is actually also the `donorNo` ??  If so, that cannot be the key in that table...

Comment: -1 For incomplete question. Read @CharlesBretana comment and complete your question and use proper tags.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT (*) FROM Donor.Certificate C
LEFT JOIN Donor D ON .No = C.No
WHERE certificate = Gold
```

Try something like that, you haven't been very clear with your schema so you will have to adjust

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a field that will relate *Donor* table to *certificate* and add a certificate field then

Donors table:

```
(one)
Donor No*
Donor Name
Donor Address
Donor Phone
Donor E-mail
Donor Certificate_Type
```

Certificates table:

```
(many)
Certificate No*
Certificate_Type
Certificate Issue Date
```

The SQL, read more about left join

```
SELECT count(*)
FROM Donors
LEFT JOIN Certificate
ON Donors.Certificate_Type=Certificate.Certificate_Type
WHERE Donors.Certificate_Type = 'the type'
```

Answer (score 0):

As Charlest Bretana has indicated, the DDL you have showed us does not show a mechanism for relating Certificates to Donors.  Without such a mechanism, it becomes much harder to query your database based on the expectation of a particular relationship between your data.

Your dependent table, Certificates, needs to possess a Foreign Key for the Donors table to indicate which Donor owns the Certificate.  This is the easiest and most common way to indicate a relationship.

```
(one)
Donor No*
Donor Name
Donor Address
Donor Phone
Donor E-mail
And is a one to many relationship in the Certificate table with attributes

(many)
Certificate No*
Foreign Key Donor No*
Certificate Type
Certificate Issue Date
```